# Is card-scan plus SMS-pin cosnidered as two-factor authentication?

Tags: security, authentication, authorization, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

Here is the scenario:

For a person to become a member of a club, the person needs to register and upon registration the member:

- must provide a mobile number
- is given a unique card associated with
  his or her person

In order for the member to make use of the club computers and services, the person must:

1. Step 1: get the physical card scanned in front of a machine (RFID) stationed in a specific shop/branch/office
2. Step 2: enter a one-time-use random 4-digit code received by SMS on the mobile number originally registered.  (The code expires after 5 minutes.)

I consider the membership card as something-that-you-own and the random one-time-use code as something-that-you-know.  The card and the 4-digit code are therefore the two factors.  If the card is lost or stolen, the 4-digit-code is still unknown to the thief.  And if the mobile phone (SIM Card) is lost or stolen, the card is still required to proceed in making use of the club services.  . Hence the two are independent from each other.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: I think one can argue that both are something you have. The user does not *know* the 4 digit code, but owns his mobile phone, which can be stolen the same way as the rfid token. A pin or pattern or touchid or similar set up to unlock the phone would make it purely 2-factor I think, but the problem with that is phone configuration is probably not controlled by the organization (club).

Comment: Yes, this is the thing here.  The Membership card AND the SIM card is what is owned, but the pin code is what is known.  With the membership card alone, the user cannot access the club.  But with card, SIM and SMS, the user gets in.  

Does the user know the 4-digit code?  
Essentially, just because the user got to know the 4-digit code right now, it doesn't mean that the user does not know it.  It simply means that it's only now that the user got to learn what it is.  Without the SMS code, the user could not get in.  Hence in my opinion there r certainly 2-factors at play.

Comment: I agree with Gabor here. Using your logic, then regular 2FA in online accounts with a password and a 6 digit code by SMS is just knowing two things, making it single factor. Fact is in this situation that the user must have 2 items, the card and the phone/SIM. It doesn't matter that knowledge is transferred over the phone, it is having it that counts. Therefore this is just single factor authentication, akin to having two passwords to enter.

Answer (score 0):

It was concluded that the above scenario is a grey area, leaning however mostly to the conclusion that it is not a 2-factor-authentication scenario.

Rationale:
When someone presents a bank credit or debit card at an ATM, the person has two tools: the card and the pin.

The card is the something-that-you-own; and
The pin is the something-that-you-know.

Therefore the PIN is definitely a knowledge factor...

The above scenario also has exactly the same two tools, a card and a pin.

However

The bank card pin is theoretically stored in your mind while in the above scenario, the PIN is received by SMS.

A mind cannot be stolen.  A mobile phone can be stolen.  For these reasons, the SMS PIN seems to become an invalid knowledge factor in this case.

The argument that follows is:  What is the SMS PIN then? Why send it in the first place?

The SMS Pin seems to be a method to verify that the phone is still in your possession.  But it cannot be considered as a knowledge factor per se.